# БД sqlite3 возвращает none

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, vkontakte-api, sqlite3

Создал базу данных никнеймов и id вк, привязанных к ним. Когда я пишу  что-то в беседу вк от своего лица, то все нормально, выводит мой ник и id. Когда пишет кто-то другой, выводит None

```
nicks = sqlite3.connect('niki23.db')
cur = nicks.cursor()

nicks.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(nickname PRIMARY KEY, vk PRIMARY KEY)'.format('niki'))
nicks.commit()

nick00 = cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM niki WHERE vk == {user_id}').fetchone()
nicks.commit()
print(nick00, "- вход")
nick01 = cur.execute(f'SELECT nickname FROM niki WHERE vk == {user_id}').fetchone()
nicks.commit()
print(nick01, "- vk nick")
sam_nick = nick01
#nick01 = " ".join(map(str, nick00))
#sam_nick0 = nick01.split()


if "/ник" == msg and nick01 is not None:
        vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id':id, "message": f"Ты - @id{user_id} ({sam_nick})", 'random_id' : 0})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для того, чтобы получить ник и id пользователя, который написал чат боту, в библиотеке есть встроенные функции. Я бы рекомендовал использовать их

Comment: Если говорить именно о вашей проблеме, то надо проверить переменную `user_id` в момент, когда пишет другой пользователь, а также что вернёт выполнение sql запроса по этому id вне чат бота и тд.
Возможно id нет в базе данных или значение переменной `user_id` некорректно в момент отправки сообщения другим пользователем